# Rails: Create form for @score while in different model no direct associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I want to create a multiple form for editing scores from a different model.

The main model is a Formrule model that consists of a habtm association with a Scoretype model
and has a habtm association with a Room model.

Both models are used to query a Scores model resulting in a @scores instance. It is for this instance I want to create a form, but the problem is that no field_for are being created. I know that the @scores is populated correctly, but the form does not show up.

This is the form as I have it now

```
<%= form_tag '/scores/update_scores' do %>
  <table>
    <tr>...</tr>
      <% for score in @scores %>
        <% fields_for :scores, score do |score| %>
           <tr>
              <td>
               <%= score.hidden_field(:form_id) %>
               <%= score.hidden_field(:team_id) %>
               <%= score.hidden_field(:scoretype_id) %>
            </td>
            <td>
              <%= score.number_field :scorevalue %>
            </td>
         </tr>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </table>
  <%= submit_tag 'Update' %>
<% end %>
```

And these are the Models:
Formrule

```
class Formrule < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :form
  has_and_belongs_to_many :scoretypes
  has_and_belongs_to_many :rooms
  has_many :teams, :through => :rooms
end
```

Scoretype

```
class Scoretype < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :scores
  has_and_belongs_to_many :formrules
end
```

Room

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :teams
  has_and_belongs_to_many :formrules
end
```

Team

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :scores
  belongs_to :room
  belongs_to :group
end
```

Score

```
class Score < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :form
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :scoretype
  validates_uniqueness_of :id, :scope => [:team, :scoretype]
end
```

And finally, the used controller (Formrule)

```
  def show
    @formrule = Formrule.find(params[:id])
    @scoretypes = @formrule.scoretypes.all.collect
    @rooms = @formrule.rooms.all.collect
    @teams = Team.find(:all, :conditions => {:room_id => @rooms})
    @scores = Score.order("team_id").all(:conditions => {:scoretype_id => @scoretypes, :team_id => @teams})
...
```

end

Why is the form not showing up? any suggestions?

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<%= fields_for ... %>` instead of `<% fields_for ...%>`.